# Does MySQL store anywhere the timestamp of modified record?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am using MySQL 5.1.35 database.
I want to know the timestamp of last modified record in a table.
I want to know it without creating extra field in table like `last_modified` with `Timestamp` type.

Does MySQL store anywhere the timestamp of modified record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. If you want that - you need to create a separate `timestamp` column for that

Comment: Thanks @zerkms for quick reply. I thought mysql should store somewhere the timestamp like it maintains the "rowid" etc.

Comment: Ok Thanks for clearing me that it is not possible without creating "timestamp" column